strongly connected directed graph with exactly one indegree per vertex proof
How can we prove in a strongly connected directed graph with exactly one indegree per vertex that each vertex will be reached, and the cycle will return to the starting point?

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.
